# Tool like Media File Segmenter for Linux

Tags: linux, video, editing

I'm looking for a tool for Linux which can segment a video file into multiple small .ts files.

I know one for Mac OS X called Media File Segmenter which is a simple command line tool - I'm looking for an equivalent tool for Linux.

Answer (score 7):

Others have mentioned [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org); it now has a nice, clean [segment muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment). On Linux, instead of relying on whatever (outdated) version of `ffmpeg` comes with your package manager, you should [download a static build](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) or [compile it from source](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/CompilationGuide).

To split a video into several one-minute segments, also generating an m3u8 playlist & copying all streams (so lossless, but not entirely accurate cutting):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mpg -c copy -f segment \
-segment_time 60 -segment_list list.m3u8 output%03d.ts
```

For accurate splitting, the documentation recommends re-encoding and using `-force_key_frames` to ensure that there will be [I-frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I-frame) on the times that the segment muxer will attempt to split on (see also the [libx264](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) and [AAC](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/AACEncodingGuide) encoding guides on the [ffmpeg wiki](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki)):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mpg -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset veryfast -c:a libfdk_aac -vbr 3 \
-force_key_frames expr:gte(t,n_forced*60) -f segment \
-segment_time 60 -segment_list list.m3u8 output%03d.ts
```

Comment: Wich I could give you two upvotes so this sits on top of the two other posts with the `sameq` in them ;)

Answer (score 2):

if you want to cut video from H.264 you should use:

```
ffmpeg -i Black_Lagoon_E10.mkv -ss 00:08:55 \
-c copy -t 00:00:32 \
-vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts Ostanovites.ts
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/).  It's powerful & cross-platform.  It may already exist in your linux distro.  To copy 2 minutes of video after the first and convert from mpg to ts:

```
ffmpeg -vcodec copy -ss 00:01:00 -t 00:03:00 \
       -i input.mpg -vcodec copy -acodec copy \
       -f mpegts output.ts
```

It's a good choice if you have lots of videos in essentially random formats.  It's a 'swiss army knife' for video.

If you are starting with mpeg, you could also try [mpegtx](http://mpgtx.sourceforge.net/), which includes a variety of mpeg tools including a splitter.  Easier IMHO than ffmpeg to split.  To split a file into 10 chunks each with a basename of 'chunk':

```
mpgtx -10 input.mpg -b chunk
```

You may also be able to use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) as a splitter, but I never have.  There are [topics discussing it](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=19474), however.

Answer (score 0):

Try [dvbcut](http://dvbcut.sourceforge.net/) if you want something with a UI.

[image]

Comment: Sorry if I missed it, but it seems to only work with DV or similar formats, not with, say, H.264 encoded video?