# How to split a video file into smaller chunks in Linux?

Tags: linux, video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tool like Media File Segmenter for Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/105387/tool-like-media-file-segmenter-for-linux)

I know that ffmpeg can extract a smallfile.avi from a largfile.avi. But what I am looking for is a tool/command to split a large video into several smaller videos of a given size.

Comment: OK, I found the perfect tool for splitting avi videos: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/avisplit.1.html

Comment: Why not go add that to the linked 'dupe' as an answer?  Seems like a good one. :)

Comment: You don't need to install any software on Linux to do that. This is not Windows ^^ Look at my answer. Cheers.

Comment: @techie007 Apparently I can not answer my own question. but I'll be happy to give the answer elsewhere, if you provide the link of the duplicate question.

Comment: NP, It shows in your question now.

Answer (score -1):

Use *split* tool available for all UNIX-like systems. For example, to split a file in 100 MiB chunks.

```
split –bytes=100m /path/to/large/file /path/to/output/file/prefix
```

Refer to the manual for more information ([man split](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?split))

Comment: Using split will not result in valid avi files.

Comment: The question didn't ask for valid AVI files. The question began by pointing out that this was *not* the functionality desired. The question starts out by pointing out a way to create smaller valid AVI files and then says "But What I am looking for is" ...

Comment: @David - Don't be silly, of course he wants valid files. Otherwise he wouldn't have mentioned ffmpeg.

Comment: @m0skit0 I had tried split and it led to faulty clips (quality lost), hence I started asking the question.